# Woocommerce фиксированная скидка в купонах

Tags: php, woocommerce

Столкнулся с неясной проблемой в woo при применении купонов.

При создании купона с процентной скидкой в корзине, при исключении нескольких категорий скидка происходит корректно. (Она применяется ко всем товарам, исключая исключенные).

А вот при создании купона с фиксированной скидкой в корзине при исключении нескольких категорий, скидка происходит некорректно:

Если в корзине имеется хотябы один исключенный товар, то при применении купона выходит сообщение "Жаль, но этот купон не распространяется на категории: Наборы."

По идее, также как при значении в процентах он должен был посчитать сидку только все товары, исключая исключенные.

Как при фиксированном значении скидки в купоне сделать так, чтобы он давал скидку на все товары, исключая исключенные?

Comment: Что такое исключенные товары?

Comment: Попробую с конкретикой:

Имеются два купона. Один с фиксированной, другой с % скидкой в корзине:

http://joxi.ru/12M5ZQyu4jOMj2

Корректнее будет не товары даже, а исключенные категории (те категории товара, к которым купон не должен применятся).

http://joxi.ru/RmzobgjcWyl0p2

При применении купона с % скидкой в корзине и исключенной категорией товаров, он работает корректно:

http://joxi.ru/DmBZzEKHNbQJxm

При применении купона с фикс. значением и исключенной категорией, происходит сообщение:

http://joxi.ru/xAeBveZUYjBR8r